# Mapbox JS - Exception on cluster count layer

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I got a Mapbox map with multiple cluster and a non-cluster layers which work witout exceptions. But when I try to add a cluster count layer, I obtain the following error in console : **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'point_count' in undefined**.

I followed [the Mapbox cluster tutorial](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/), but cannot see why this bug is showing up.

Here is my code :

```
function setMyApplicationLayers(map, layers) {
    getMyApplicationLayers().forEach(function(layer) {
        map.addLayer(layer);
    })
}

function getMyApplicationLayers() {
    var layers = [getMyApplicationRestaurantItemLayer()];

    ['#ef59a1', '#6ecff6', '#d7df21']
            .forEach(function(color, index) {
        layers.push(getMyApplicationRestaurantGroupLayer(index, color));
    });

    layers.push(getMyApplicationRestaurantCountLayer());

    return layers;
}

function getMyApplicationRestaurantItemLayer() {
    return {
        id: 'unclustered-restaurants',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'my-application-restaurants',
        layout: {
            'icon-image': 'marker-15'
        }
    }
}

function getMyApplicationRestaurantGroupLayer(index, color) {
    return {
        id: 'clustered-restaurants-' + index,
        type: 'circle',
        source: 'my-application-restaurants',
        paint: {
            'circle-color': color,
            'circle-radius': 18
        },
        filter: getMyApplicationRestaurantGroupLayerFilter(index)
    }
}

function getMyApplicationRestaurantGroupLayerFilter(index) {
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return ['>=', 'point_count', 25]
        case 1:
            return ['all',
                ['>=', 'point_count', 5],
                ['<', 'point_count', 25]]
        case 2:
            return ['all',
                ['>=', 'point_count', 0],
                ['<', 'point_count', 5]]
    }
}

function getMyApplicationRestaurantCountLayer() {
    return {
        id: 'cluster-count',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'my-application-restaurants',
        layout: {
            'text-field': '{point_count}',
            'text-font': [
                'DIN Offc Pro Medium',
                'Arial Unicode MS Bold'
            ],
            'text-size': 12
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any problems with the posted code. Can you post a runable example that demonstrates the error?

Comment: Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dyhhqLda/2/). Try to zoom / unzoom and look at the console. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This exception stems from an incorrect GeoJSON structure.

In the provided JSFiddle you include a number of GeoJSON features structured like this one:

```
{
    type: 'Feature',
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        properties: {
            description: 'kuk'
        },
        coordinates: [2.7, 46.95]
    }
}
```

The GeoJSON specification says:

> [A *feature* object must have a member with the name "properties". The value of the properties member is an object (any JSON object or a JSON null value).](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#feature-objects)

The `properties` member should be on the `Feature` object, not the `Point` object. A correctly formatted feature would look like

```
{
    type: 'Feature',
    properties: {
        description: 'kuk'
    },
    geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: [2.7, 46.95]
    }
}
```

Here's a modified demo without the error: https://jsfiddle.net/dyhhqLda/2/